# Iterating through Panda Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Can someone help explain how I would be able to loop through this dictionary and access`'App name'`? I've tried assigning all of this to a variable, but it's still having a hard time accepting `'App Name'`.

```
{
'APPID1':
{'updated_cols': ['App Name', 'Platform Leader', 'AppOne Business Group'],         'new_vals': ['my new app', 'new pl', 'new bg'],             'old_vals': ['my old app', 'old pl', 'old bg']       }
,
'APPID2':
{'updated_cols': \['App Name', 'Platform Leader', 'AppOne Business Group'\],         'new_vals': \['my new app', 'new pl', 'new bg'\],             'old_vals': \['my old app', 'old pl', 'old bg'\]       }
....
}
```

I have tried setting this dictionary to a variable and looping through, but the only thing that is returned is `"APPID1"` and `"APPID2"`.

Answer (score 0):

I took some liberty to guess what you might be interested to do and created following as a reference

```
all_records = dict({
    'APPID1': dict({'updated_cols': ['App Name', 'Platform Leader', 'AppOne Business Group'],
                    'new_vals': ['my new app', 'new pl', 'new bg'], 
                    'old_vals': ['my old app', 'old pl', 'old bg']
                    }),
    'APPID2': dict({'updated_cols': ['App Name', 'Platform Leader', 'AppOne Business Group'],
                    'new_vals': ['my new app', 'new pl', 'new bg'],
                    'old_vals': ['my old app', 'old pl', 'old bg']
                    }),
    })

for key, record_dict in all_records.items():
  print('---'* 12 + ' ' + key)
  print('|'.join(record_dict['updated_cols']))
  print('|'.join(record_dict['old_vals']))
  print('|'.join(record_dict['new_vals']))
```

output

```sh
------------------------------------ APPID1
App Name|Platform Leader|AppOne Business Group
my old app|old pl|old bg
my new app|new pl|new bg
------------------------------------ APPID2
App Name|Platform Leader|AppOne Business Group
my old app|old pl|old bg
my new app|new pl|new bg
```

I would suggest you to go through Python basics once more. Learn a bit more about lists, dict and set data types.

Comment: Why do you wrap *literal* ``{`` ``}`` dicts into ``dict(`` ``)`` *calls*? The literals are sufficient to create the dicts, the calls just needlessly copy the result.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - In python3 use of curly braces are not necessarily accepted as a dict data type. So if I do `temp = {1, 2, 3,}` is a valid assignment. I use `dict` call as a safety check. If by change one forget to add `:`, then this dict call will do the required checks